Auth0 iFrame login works on Firefox, but not on Chrome/Safari
Our web app uses Auth0 as an authentication provider. Typically, this works great. Recently we're running into an issue where when the login flow is run through an iFrame (embedded in Shopify) we receive an error and the login fails. The weird part is that the flow works consistently in Firefox, but not in Chrome or Safari. Originally it wasn't working at all, but switching to classic login and changing settings for cross-origin authentication and clickjacking protection fixed the issue.
These are the console errors we're receiving. The first is Safari (fails to login), then Firefox (success).
Help!!
Firefox 1 Firefox 2 Firefox 3 Safari
Adding allowed origins, classic login, multiple browsers. Problem occurs only in browsers other than Firefox.

three of those images are completely unreadable to my (old) eyes - and why would you torture young eyes like that :p

Did you setup custom domains at Auth0? See https://manage.auth0.com/dashboard/[REGION]/[TENANT]/custom_domains You would need to setup that along with a DNS entry for your custom login sub domain, pointing to [TENANT+SOMETHING].edge.tenants.[REGION].auth0.com Also try and block third party cookies in Firefox, and see if that stops working too. (Or enable in in Chrome.)
